# Column and Row Picture for Singular System of 100 Equations (Strang P55, 2.2.32)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Start with 100 equations $\color{#8F00FF}{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ for $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, ..., x_{1oo})$. Suppose elimination reduces the 100th equation to $0 = 0$, so the system is "singular".
>
> (a) Elimination takes linear combinations of the rows. So this singular system has
>   the singular property: Some linear combination of the 100 rows is $\color{green}?$.
>
> (b) Singular systems $\color{purple}{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ have infinitely many solutions. This means that some linear combination of the 100 columns is $\color{  #FF4F00}{??}$.
>
> (d) For a 100 by 100 singular matrix with no zero entries, describe in words the row picture and the column picture of
>   $\color{  #9966CC}{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$. Not necessary to draw 100-dimensional space.

**My Attempt for (a) and (b):** The question postulates that for all $ 1 \leq r \leq 100, \sum_{c = 1}^{100}\color{#8F00FF}{a_{rc}}x_c=0.$ Pictorially:
[image]
Hitherto, my definition of "singular" is "dependent rows or columns" (cf P27). So $? = \color{green}{\vec{0}}$ and $?? = \color{  #FF4F00}{\vec{0}}$.

> **Averred Answer for (d):** The row picture has $100$ planes meeting along a common line $\color{#0073CF}{\text{through } \vec{0}}$. The
>   column picture has $100$ vectors all in the same $\color{#0073CF}{99}$-dimensional hyperplane.

$\Large{1.}$ Why must the common line be $\color{#0073CF}{\text{through } \vec{0}}$? Why not any common line?

$\Large{2.}$ $A$ contains $100$ columns so $100$ column vectors. But $A$ also contains $100$ rows, so how and why $\color{#0073CF}{99}$-dimensional hyperplane?

Please mind that this question is from a germinal section of *IoLA, 4th ed* by Strang.

Answer (score -1):

elimination takes linear combinations of the rows. So this singular system has singular property some linear combination of the 100 row is non singular 
singular systems Ax=0 have infinitely many solutions This means that some linear combination of the 100 columns is non zero
when Ax=0 then linear combination of rows and columns will be same and donot have value greater than zero,